# How to set fmask, dmask or umask on OS X?

Tags: macos, permission, mount

I want external drives mounted with specified permissions. I know that *fmask*, *dmask* and *umask* in *fstab* do this trick.

I added this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=D2-HT250   none    msdos   rw,auto,fmask=0122 0 0
```

But when I checked file permissions, still `rwxrwxrwx`. OS X simply ignored the `fmask=0122` option.

How to set masks on OS X? (I am using OS X 10.9 Mavericks.)

Comment: To be clear, OS X permission model is more layered than POSIX. Is there an end goal other than setting the underlying posix permissions which ACL will trump always anyhow? (Basically this looks like a classic XY question)

Comment: Since it's being mounted as an `msdos` volume, and assuming it's formatted `FAT32`, then therein lies your problem as FAT32 does not support basic Unix permissions and all files and folders will always show `rwxrwxrwx`.